# Increasing the 'Drop Here' area when 'dragging and dropping' Documents in a LVWP

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sitepages, drag-and-drop

I want to make the 'Drop Here' area as big as possible. I'm assuming that the size of the 'Drop Here' area corresponds with the size of the LVWP. Is there a way to increase it?
Picture included below. Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Script Editor` on your page that has your Document Library

[image]

Add this CSS style

```
<style>
#ms-dnd-dropbox
{

height: 500px ! important;


}
</style>
```

Increase the height based on your requirements

**[OutPut]**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however, no dice. I put it directly into my Style Sheet and it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: should you try it first in script editor to make sure it's working !! i attached a screenshot with my output :)

Comment: you are right :) , I checked it again , I found out I missed something! I have updated my answer , should you check it again :)

Comment: Put it in a Script Editor, and still not working. I've removed some branding in my page...is it possible that it could be causing problems? None of the css style sheet currently loaded mentions the 'ms-dnd-dropdown'. Thoughts?

Comment: I updated the answer are you checed the new update <style>
#ms-dnd-dropbox
{

height: 500px ! important;


}
</style>

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much. I am going to add a 'top' attribute to this, as well. Thanks again. This is great.

Comment: Glad to here it's working , and you are welcome my bro :)